# Creating a Django model that stores a randomly selected list of objects from another model

Tags: django, django-models

Summary: I'm creating an app that involves exams, categories and questions, each exam, when created, will query data from each catagory, each category will then return a pre-determined number of random questions from themselves

1. Exam needs 25 questions from category A and 25 from category B.
2. Category A and B both return 25 items each.
3. The exam model needs to store these 50 items.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to go about storing the returned data in the exam model. I know it's just gonna be question IDs but can I store them in a string CharField? The number of questions per exam can get to around 200 and question IDs are expected to be around four to five digits in length too.

Is there a better way to do this than storing it in a string? I can't store the selection criteria because I'm going to be using randomization/shuffling...

I think the actual solution would be simple but I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out lol.

Can I just use both ForeignKey and ManyToMany for Category-Question and Exam-Question?

Comment: Use foreign keys (direct ones or many to many). Anything else is wrong relational db design.